# Ascending order of SXA main navigation items

Tags: sxa

I'm working on a project that has already been started for a while, the main navigation is displayed correctly but in Sitecore it is reversed.
For example in Sitecore:

> - Home
>
>   - Contact Us
>   - Project
>   - About

On public site:

> - About
> - Project
> - Contact Us

So for some reason SXA is reversing the order of the Sitecore tree items.

Is this configured somewhere or is it intentional? We're using SXA 1.4.

Comment: Did you check you CSS floating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to sort items displayed in the SXA Navigation rendering (no specific setting for this). The order is based on order of items in the tree.

Check if the order of items in the content tree is the same in the master and web databases.

Comment: It is the same. But your answer made me look outside Sitecore, it turns out is is a bug in our custom css file. Thank you